# Add one-way streets to network data in postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I want to create a routable network.
Doing that, I downloaded OSM data and created a topology with `pgr_createTopology()` (http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html). 
However, I wonder: How would I add the information of the flow of direction to the streets? Somehow I must tell `pg_routing` that a street from this vertice to to another is a one-way-street.
I know these to sources: http://www.webrian.ch/2011/07/set-up-pgrouting-with-openstreetmap.html
http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/oneway.html but it does not say how I in which direction the traffic flows.

Answer (score 4):

In pgRouting the direction is always from `source` to `target`.

When you run `pgr_createTopology()`, then `source` is the start point of your line geometry and `target` is the end point.

If you want to model one-way streets, then you do this using costs. There is the `cost` attribute for the costs to travel from `source` to `target` and the `reverse_cost` attribute for the opposite direction.

When the `cost` (or `reverse_cost`) is negative (for example `-1`), then this direction will not be taken into account and is excluded from the graph. So for a one-way street you assign `-1` for the `cost` or `reverse_cost` attribute of your edge, depending on the direction of the restriction.

Comment: But how does `pgr_createTopology()` know whats is `source` and `target`?

Comment: Maybe a look at the sample data in the documentation helps to understand how it needs to look like: http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html#sampledata

Comment: There are PostGIS functions `ST_startPoint()` and `ST_endPoint()`, and they give you the start and end point of your linestring geometry. So when you draw your edge, you start with a first point, which is the start point and you end with the last point, which becomes the end point. It just depends, how the geometry was created.

Comment: If you want to see the SQL, this is the section of the `pgr_createTopology()`, where it assigns `source` and `target` for each edge. https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/topology/sql/pgrouting_topology.sql#L239-L244
There is no particular rule except the geometry information.

Comment: With a small dataset that looks fairly easy. However, how would you do that with a networkdataset for a whole city - i.e. extractred from OSM?

Comment: You better use osm2pgrouting, if you import OSM data. 
Otherwise, if you do not know how the one-way streets are directed based on the geometry of the edge, then you won't be able to assign costs correctly.

Comment: But with `osm2pgrouting` `pgr_createTopology()` will know it?

Comment: osm2pgrouting is the special import tool for OSM data, and it will care about one-way restrictions. It does not require anymore the use of `pgr_createTopology()`. You best start with the pgRouting workshop, I would suggest.